# Discord Bot: Only post tweets that contain keywords

Tags: twitter, discord, winston, discord.io

I am trying to create a discord bot that will post tweets from a twitter account that announces alerts for a game. It announces several types of alerts, however  I only want to post a single kind of alert to the discord. Fortunately, each tweet starts with a hashtag that differentiates it.

I want the bot to essentially do this:

```
current_tweet=get.tweet(Games_Alert_Twitter_Account);
if(current_tweet.substring(0,keyword_length) =='Keyword')
post(Keyword);
else
do_nothing();
```

I have found plenty of resources of how to pull tweets from a user using webhooks or APIs that will just do it for you, but I haven't found any sources on how to pull tweets as they go up, look to see if it begins or contains a certain keyword, then post if it does or do nothing if it does not.

In summary I need this:

1) Check if a specific user on twitter (the game company) has made a post

2) Take the content of that post and put into a form that I can use to see if the message contains certain keywords

3)Post a message to the discord channel according to the keyword in step 2 (I can do this part already)

Does anyone know of an API that would support this? I am pretty new to the discord and twitter APIs and pretty rusty with my coding skills so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

(EDIT): I added a summary and changed the last step I need

Comment: What do you meany by?
"pull tweets as they go up"

Comment: "post tweet completely"?

Comment: @SheikhAzad Sorry for the clarity issues. What I meant to say is as the game company posts these alert tweets, I would like for the bot to "retrieve" the post (aka put it into a form I can apply IF statements to know if it contains the information I wish to post, like an array of strings or something)

Comment: @SheikhAzad Also I have changed my mind on the "Post tweet completely" part. Since there are only a handful of different alerts, I will simply have the bot say a message about which alert has been announced by the game company using `switch` and `case` . I have edited my original post to reflect this. I have also added a clearer summary at the bottom of what exactly I need to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the code excerpts that you've posted, they look to have Python in mind. Tweepy's Stream API has what you're looking for. It allows you to create a stream that'll give you a constant feed of tweets from specified accounts. With that you can do whatever you'd like.

**From Tweepy Docs**

> In Tweepy, an instance of tweepy.Stream establishes a streaming session and routes messages to StreamListener instance. The on_data method of a stream listener receives all messages and calls functions according to the message type. The default StreamListener can classify most common twitter messages and routes them to appropriately named methods, but these methods are only stubs.

http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html

Answer (score 0):

@SRyan There are things that the API wont do for you and you would be responsible for processing them.
I am more proficient in PHP, so I will provide my sample code in PHP.

From what I understand, you need the statuses/users_timeline endpoint.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

It returns a collection of the most recent Tweets posted by the user indicated by the screen_name or user_id parameters. You can poll your calls every x minutes. You can make 900 requests every 15 minutes. That is a huge amount of calls to get the latest tweets posted by a user.

Please make sure to filter out retweets.
Each tweet would contain an array of hashtags, user_mentions, symbols, urls. You can create your own BOW (bag of words) to test against the available hashtags and proceed accordingly.

I am using Abraham's Twitter OAuth PHP library.
The code below is not tested and I just typed as it came to mind.

```
$params = [
    //users screen name whose tweets you want to fetch
    'screen_name' => '@sheikhazad', 
    //number of tweets to return, max 200 per request
    'count'=>100,
    //fetch tweets later than a given id, set this to blank if you want to fetch from the oldest. only the last 3200 are available
    'since_id'=> '',
    //exclude replies if you want
    'exclude_replies' => 1 
];
$statuses = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', $params);
$array_of_hashtags_to_match = []; //fill with key hashtags
$array_of_words = []; //fill with key words
//to keep track of latest id fetched for future calls
$max_id = $params['since_id']; 

foreach($statuses->statuses as $status){
    //skip retweets
    if($status->retweeted_status && $status->retweeted_status->text != '')
        continue;
    //skip tweets that do not not begin with a hashtag, remove if not needed
    else if(!$status->entities || !$status->entities->hashtags)
        continue;
    //skip tweets that do not have hashtags
    else if(!$status->entities || !$status->entities->hashtags)
        continue;

    //if you want to match hashtags
    foreach($status->entities->hashtags as $htag){
        //check if the hashtag
        if(in_array(strtolower($htag, $array_of_hashtags_to_match))){
             //post to discord as needed
        }
    }

    //tokenize the tweet text, i.e., $status->text
    $tokens = array_unique(explode(' ', strtolower($status->text)));
    //either use array intersection to find if there are matching keywords
    //or use a loop to iterate through each keyword, check if present
    //post to discord as needed
}
```